# How do I get GNU make to output the commands it executes to builds its targets

Tags: makefile, gnu

none of the --debug= flags seem to do it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `make -n` ?

Comment: The -n is "dry-run".  While it shows commands that would be run, it doesn't actually run any of them, so it cannot be used to debug exactly where a build is failing.

Comment: `remake -x`  like the solution below that changes SHELL will show the commands during a run, even if the commands are explicitly non-echoed by preceding the commands with @. See http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/

Answer (score 6):

```
make SHELL='sh -vx'
```

may also be helpful.